# classification_report vs f1_score in scikit-learn's classification metrics

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

What is the right way to evaluate a binary classifier using scikit-learn's evaluation metrics?

Given y_test and y_pred as the gold and predicted labels, shouldn't the F1 score in the classification_report output be the same as what f1_score produces?

Here is how I do it:

```
print(classification_reprot(y_test, y_pred)
```

gives the following table:

```
         precision    recall  f1-score   support

      0       0.49      0.18      0.26       204
      1       0.83      0.96      0.89       877

avg / total       0.77      0.81      0.77      1081
```

However,

```
print(f1_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

gives F1 score = 0.89

Now, given the above outputs, is the performance of this model F1 score = 0.89 or is it 0.77?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short, for your case, the *f1-score* is 0.89, and the *weighted average f1-score* is 0.77.

Take a look at the docstring of `sklearn.metrics.f1_score`:

```
The F1 score can be interpreted as a weighted average of the precision and
recall, where an F1 score reaches its best value at 1 and worst score at 0.
The relative contribution of precision and recall to the F1 score are
equal. The formula for the F1 score is::

    F1 = 2 * (precision * recall) / (precision + recall)

In the multi-class and multi-label case, this is the weighted average of
the F1 score of each class.
```

The key is the final sentence here. If you're looking for the weighted average f1 score for each class, then you shouldn't feed the function a 0/1 binary classification. So, for example, you could do

```
f1_score(y_test + 1, y_pred + 1)
# 0.77
```

If the class labels are not 0/1, then it is treated as a multiclass metric (where you care about all precision/recall scores) rather than a binary metric (where you care about precision/recall only for positive samples). I agree that this might be a bit surprising, but in general 0/1 classes are treated as a marker of binary classification.

---

Edit: some of the behavior listed here is deprecated since Scikit-learn 0.16 – in particular the confusing implicit assumptions about binary vs non-binary classifications. See [this github thread](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/2679) for details.